# Coding an inner class with Point as outer class

Tags: java, class, inner-classes, nested-class

For an assignment I need to create a class within class Point from java.awt.Point. I need to be able to use point methods while creating my own variables for the inner/nested class. I am a bit confused by the differences between static nested classes and inner classes and dont know which one to use. I have tried to use a static nested class and have encountered an error stating "modifier static not allowed here"

My misguided attempt:

```
class Point {
    static class RobotJAW {

        int goldcollected, x, y;

        RobotJAW() {
            goldcollected = 0;
            alive = true;
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
        }

    }
}
```

The point of creating this class it to have a robot search a field of gold and bombs and collect gold while being destroyed by bombs. I can only use the Point and Scanner classes from the java API. I need to use the point methods equals(obj), move(int x, int y), getLocation(), and setLocation(int x, int y). But I need to add goldcollected and alive variables. Also, this is an assignment for school, so I would like to gain some more knowledge about the subject, and some guidance, without being given someone elses work.

Comment: Welcome, new user! Historically, we've had some issues with people just wanting to have code handed to them, so it's nice to see "I would like to gain some more knowledge about the subject, and some guidance, without being given someone elses work."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lesson about how inner classes work, then some doubts that that is what you really need.
An inner class is used for describing a class with an extremely strong belongs-to relationship to another class. So strong infact, that it cannot survive without the outer class. So strong, that you rarely need it.  The inner class is only accessible through an instance of the outer class:

```
public class A{
  public int value1;
  public class B{
    public int value2;
  }
}
...
A a1 = new A()
a1.value1 = 202
A.B b1 = new a1.B();
System.out.println(b1.value1); //Prints 202
A.B b2 = new B(); //Compiler error! Not allowed
```

A static inner class is not really an inner class. It is just a class that is defined inside of an inner class.

It looks to me like what you want is for RobotJaw to either **be a point**, or **have a point**. You don't want it to be an object unattachably contained by a point. So either have RobotJaw extend a Point, or contain a point.

Comment: If the constructor for RobotJAW contained a point would I still be able to add my own variables and still use point methods on the object?

Comment: @user1043550 If it contained a point, you could add a .getLocation() method that returned the point, and then you could operate on that. Of course you could add anything you wanted to RobotJAW itself, so yes.

Answer (score 1):

> For an assignment I need to create a class within class Point from java.awt.Point.

You can only create an class within an class if you have the source code for the outer class and can recompile it.  You can't do this for `java.awt.Point`.

If you think your assignment is *telling* you to do that, you are *probably* misinterpreting what your assignment is saying.

Certainly, it doesn't make a lot of sense to create a nested class inside `Point`.  AFAIK, there's nothing (sensible) that a class nested in Point could do that can't be done by a non-nested class.  Maybe the assignment is asking for you to `extend` the `Point` class; i.e. create a subclass rather than a nested class.

---

<sub>(Actually, it is theoretically possible to do this, but not with pure Java; e.g.</sub>

- <sub>You could download the source-code of OpenJDK, add your nested class to java.awt.Point and rebuild.  But what you'd end up with is NOT Java.</sub>
- <sub>You could use bytecode magic to build a classfile for a nested class.  Provided you got it right, it would be loadable, and (I think) it would be able to access private methods and attributes of the outer class.  But this is not pure Java.</sub>

<sub>Both approaches are thoroughly bad ideas, and this is almost certainly not what your assignment expects you to do.)</sub>